# multiple select with minimum one selected

Tags: html, select

i have a problem with the select and the multiple attribute: i want to have at least minimum 1 option selected, but dont want to use javascript for it. is this even possible without js? the select box looks like this

```
<select class="span6 m-wrap" id="search_sites" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
  <option value="Category 1" selected="selected">Category 1</option>
  <option value="Category 2" selected="selected">Category 2</option>
  <option value="Category 2" selected="selected">Category 3</option>
  <option value="Category 3" selected="selected">Category 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There's the HTML5 `required` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without Javascript.
There is the [HTML5 required tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp) but it is not supported for selects.

Javascript option in case you need it anyway:

Check this is true before proceeding.

```
  alert($('#search_sites').val() != null)
```

Comment: That's not true. `required` **is** supported on *selects*. [W3 HTML5 Select](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<select multiple required ... >`

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select multiple required class="span6 m-wrap" id="search_sites" size="3" tabindex="1">
    <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="Category 2">Category 3</option>
    <option value="Category 3">Category 4</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```